# qq plot in loop not plotting

Tags: r, for-loop, jpeg

I am trying to create a loop that graphs diagnostic plots of multiple mixed models so that I can easily see if the assumptions of the model are met. I am running models on 7 measurements of 5 species so creating the plots for all 35 models individually would really suck.

My code is:

```
sink("C:\\Users\\*My Name*\\Desktop\\Morph Data\\JAWE\\LMM2\\JAWEj LMM Output.txt")

Names<-names(int)

result.sum <- vector("list",16)
names(result.sum)<-Names

result.aov <- vector("list",16)
names(result.aov)<-Names

for(i in 9:15){
blah<-data.frame(X=int$Year,Y=int[,i],Z=int$Observer)
blah<-blah[complete.cases(blah),]
mod1<-lme(Y~X,random=~1|Z,method="ML",data=blah)
result.sum[[i]]<-summary(mod1)
result.aov[[i]]<-anova(mod1)


mypath=file.path("C:","Users","*My Name*","Desktop","Morph Data","JAWE","LMM2", paste(Names[i],"_qq",".jpg",sep=""))
jpeg(file=mypath)
p<-qqnorm(mod1,main=Names[i])
dev.off()

mypath=file.path("C:","Users","*My Name*","Desktop","Morph Data","JAWE","LMM2", paste(Names[i],"_res-hist",".jpg",sep=""))
jpeg(file=mypath)
hist(mod1$residuals[,1],freq=FALSE,main="Wing")
curve(dnorm(x,mean=mean(mod1$residuals[,1]),sd=sd(mod1$residuals[,1]),log=FALSE), col=2, lwd=4, lty=4, add=TRUE)
dev.off()

mypath=file.path("C:","Users","*My Name*","Desktop","Morph Data","JAWE","LMM2", paste(Names[i],"_res",".jpg",sep=""))
jpeg(file=mypath)
plot(blah$X,mod1$residuals[,1],main="Wing")
dev.off()
}

result.sum
result.aov
```

The object int is my data for this particular species, JAWE. With this code I can successfully save the output from the models and ANOVAs, and 2 of the 3 graphs per model.

The problem I am running into is that the saved Q-Q plots are blank plot space. Any clues on how to fix this would be most appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually the `qqnorm.lme` function returns a "trellis" object, unlike the base `qqnorm.default` function that usees base graphics. You've assigned the result to `p`, but you need to actually `plot(p)` or `print(p)` to get the object to actually draw.

Comment: Thank you so much, MrFlick! That fixed the problem!